# Update in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5 in my project and I want to update a record. How do I do this?

Here is my base class.

```
using System;  

namespace EF_Sample09.DomainClasses  
{  
    public abstract class BaseEntity  
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }  

        public DateTime CreatedOn { set; get; }  
        public string CreatedBy { set; get; }  

        public DateTime ModifiedOn { set; get; }  
        public string ModifiedBy { set; get; }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Im assuming you want an example of how to perform an update using EF?

Answer (score 0):

Taking from the great [ADO.NET Entity Framework Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

```
using(AdventureWorksDB aw = new 
AdventureWorksDB(Settings.Default.AdventureWorks)) {
    // find all people hired at least 5 years ago
    Query<SalesPerson> oldSalesPeople = aw.GetQuery<SalesPerson>(
        "SELECT VALUE sp " +
        "FROM AdventureWorks.AdventureWorksDB.SalesPeople AS sp " +
        "WHERE sp.HireDate < @date",
        new QueryParameter("@date", DateTime.Today.AddYears(-5)));

    foreach(SalesPerson p in oldSalesPeople) {
        // call the HR system through a webservice to see if this
        // sales person has a promotion coming (note that this
        // entity type is XML-serializable)
        if(HRWebService.ReadyForPromotion(p)) {
            p.Bonus += 10; // give a raise of 10% in the bonus
            p.Title = "Senior Sales Representative"; // give a promotion 
        }
    }

    // push changes back to the database
    aw.SaveChanges();
}
```

You basically just have to:

- create your `ObjectContext` (or `DbContext`)
- fetch some records
- modify the objects
- call the context's `.SaveChanges()` method to write those changes back to the database

That's it!